# Split String with unicode and backslash with Python

Tags: python, unicode, split, web-scraping

I am experiencing trouble extracting a float from a string. The string is the output of webscraping:

```
input = u'<strong class="ad-price txt-xlarge txt-emphasis " itemprop="price">\r\n\xa3450.00pw</strong>'
```

I want to get:

`output: 3450.00`

but I didn't find a way to do it. I have tried to extract it with the split / replace functions:

```
word.split("\xa")
word.replace('<strong class="ad-price txt-xlarge txt-emphasis " itemprop="price">\r\n\xa','')
```

I tried to use the `re` library. It does not work as well, it only extract `450.00`

```
import re
num = re.compile(r'\d+.\d+')
num.findall(word)
[u'450.00']
```

Thus, I still have the same problem in the end with the `\`
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: What do you mean ? The functions I tried to use ?

Comment: Yes.. We want to see your code so that we can help you out on where you went wrong

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
input.encode('utf-8').split('\xa3')[1].split('pw')[0]

>> 450.00
```

Voilà

Comment: But you don't even know what `pw` is supposed to be. That may not be an invariant.

Comment: Good try, it does not though. I want to extract 3450.00

Comment: @Jb_Eyd `\xa3450.00` is literally `PS450.00`

Comment: @th3an0maly Thanks a lot !!! I didn't realise it was part of the unicode !

Comment: No need to encode, just split on `u'\xa3'` instead, but really the OP's original `re` solution was already giving the correct answer, but didn't realize it.

Answer (score 1):

`\xa3` is the pound sign.

```
import unidecode 
print unidecode.unidecode(input)

<strong class="ad-price txt-xlarge txt-emphasis " itemprop="price">
PS450.00pw</strong>
```

To get the number from that, you better use regex:

```
import re
num = re.compile(r'\d+.\d+')
num.findall(input)[0]
```

**Result**

```
'450.00'
```

Comment: Almost! In fact you do not get the right result, you do not extract 3450.00 but only 450.00

Comment: It's real answer is £450.00. Then why you want 345.00 ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `\xa3` is the pound sign in unicode. You're trying to split a unicode character in half when you do `split('\xa')`. The output you actually want is `450.00` because `\xa3450.00` translates to `£450.00`.

```
str.split('\xa3')
```

should work in **Python 3**.

---

**Note:**
`input` is a keyword. Unless you explicitly mean to reassign it, I'd suggest not using it as a variable.

Comment: This will not work as it's a non-ascii character: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @th3an0maly That occurs because your console doesn't support unicode characters. Thats a different problem altogether. It should work in IDLE.

Comment: Coincidentally, I'm using IDLE :)

Comment: Well.. I can't post a screenshot, but it works for me.

Comment: I have removed my downvote, as I'm unsure of what's happening :)

Comment: Are you on Python 3.x or 2.x?

Comment: 2.7.11 to be precise.

Comment: Maybe that's the cause. I'm using 3.5. I'll look into the differences.

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution for that:

```
import re

x = u'<strong class="ad-price txt-xlarge txt-emphasis " itemprop="price">\r\n\xa3450.00pw</strong>'
print re.findall(r'\d+.\d*', x)
```

> output: [u'450.00']

Comment: This is a duplicate of @Rahul K P's answer.

Answer (score -1):

This code may help you:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

input = u'<strong class="ad-price txt-xlarge txt-emphasis " itemprop="price">\r\n\xa3450.00pw</strong>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
# Find all script tags
for n in soup.find_all('strong'):
    # Check if the src attribute exists
    if 'src' in n.attrs:
        value = n['src']
        print value
```

I admit I didn't run it but the output suppose to be:

> \r\n\xa3450.00pw

And from here you can extract the value easily.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, it does work because you still have the same problem. ie. extracting with the \xa around